# Skip a loop in alpine.js with x-if

Tags: forms, templates, alpine.js

I use this loop

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <template x-for="(deck, index) in $store.cart.decks">
      <div x-show="$store.cart.total(index) > 0">
        <div><span x-text="$store.cart.total(index)"></span> Karten</div>
        <div x-text="deck.price"></div> €
        <input :name="'deck[' + index + '][name]'" :value="$store.cart.decks[index].name">
      </div>
    </template>
</form>
```

Which works fine and displays all items in my cart and hides those that have a total of 0.

But this will only set the item with 0 on `display:none`, which will **still transfer the data in the POST request**.

1. I tried to use `x-if` instead of `x-show` but that is only allowed on a tempate tag.
2. I tried to add the x-if on the template tag:

   ```
   <template x-show="$store.cart.total(index) > 0" ...
   ```

   this results in an error, because `index` is not set at that point
3. I tried to add another `<template>` tag inside the existing template, but then the variables `index` and `deck` are not available inside the second any more

How do I prevent the zero cart items being computed in my POST request?

Comment: Another option is that, when you hide the div you also disable the input so that it is not sent in the request.

Answer (score 7):

I think something like the following would work, note the `div` inside both `template` elements.

```html
<template x-for="(deck, index) in $store.cart.decks">
  <div>
    <template x-if="$store.cart.total(index)">
      <div>
        <!-- rest of the content -->
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I don't understand why adding surrounding div in the templates worked, but I followed your lead and it finally worked. Thank you.

Comment: It works due to how Alpine handles templates internally in version 2.